# jquery mobile live tap

Tags: jquery, mobile, live, tap

In the jquery mobile docs (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/api/events.html) it says that you can use tap (or any of the events listed) with live and bind.

I am currently attempting to get live working with the tap event with the following:

```
$('#show_date,#final').live('tap', function () {
  //$('#divpd').dialog('open');
  $('#dialog').jqmShow();
  $('#setfoc').focus();
  return false;
}); // does not work
```

This however does not work. However the exact same thing using bind:

```
$('#show_date,#final').bind('tap', function () {
  //$('#divpd').dialog('open');
  $('#dialog').jqmShow();
  $('#setfoc').focus();
  return false;
}); // works
```

Does work.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with mobile Safari, then the source of your problem may be the buggy jquery live implementation on that platform: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5677

The bug is for a click event, but I'm guessing that 'tap' may be affected as well. A possible workaround is to make sure you are binding to an `<a>` element. Chris Williams offers another solution in his blog as well:
http://www.martinilab.com/blog/209/mobile-safari-needs-a-little-jquery-live-love/

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported bug unique to mobile safari. I believe the easiest fix is simply adding

cursor: pointer

to the CSS of the element to which you're targeting the live function.